# Can individual inset maps be added to individual pages of QGIS atlas?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

QGIS 3.20 on Windows 10 Pro.
I am about to create a 50 page atlas via QGIS Print Layout.  I wish to insert enlargements on many  pages to make congested areas on those pages more readable. On a preview, I inserted an enlargement  on one page, but that one enlargement repeats on all atlas pages.  Can QGIS handle individual enlargements on individual pages of the atlas, and if so, what is the process?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using conditional expression to "exclude items from exports" to show/hide the inset. You can also with conditional expressions position the layout item(s), their size and if necessary change page size for each element (an element refers to one feature in your coverage layer).

I recommand you to go to this video from Alexandre Neto at QGIS Open Day (2021/06/25) to get most ideas applied I mentioned above https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCsnTt6uxXo

Comment: I don't think this is Bill's question, but i may be wrong ...

Comment: Don't know. Only Bill knows ;). My understanding is that with "atlas pages", he was using module atlas so I did not repeat the "classic" atlas recipe applied to inset as you've done. He does not want the inset item to be repeated on each page of the atlas or at least not in a fixed position. So, my answer seemed to be fine too but could be wrong too ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies and your respect for alternate views.  I'll carefully go through what you have each said.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to make your inset maps **atlas-dependent** you have to check the `controlled by atlas` checkbox is checked **also** for this map.
At that stage i suppose only your "main" map is controlled by the atlas.

To control the scale of your inset maps either set it manually (**fixed scale** on every page) or set the `margin around feature` percentage to fit your needs.

Another way to control the scale of the inset maps is to use the `data defined override` to set the extent of the map by defining its xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax. This should be done *relative to the current atlas feature* using an expression like the following :

> x_min(geometry(@atlas_feature))

Which will set the **xmin** of the extent of the inset map. You can tweak the expression to add (for example) any desired calculated margin. Of course you have to do the same for ymin, xmax and ymax.